# Lisp Swap function

Tags: list, functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp, swap

I am trying to write a functional program in Lisp that requires any two elements of a list to be shaped and return the new list. So far I have:

```
(defun swap (lst x y)
  (let ((temp (nth y lst)))
   (substitute (nth x lst) (nth y lst))
   (substitute temp (nth x lst)))
```

When I run:  `(swap '(1 2 3  4 5 e 6 7 8) 5 4)`
I get:

`*** - EVAL/APPLY: too many arguments given to SWAP`

Comment: You can  use `rotatef` if you can use the index of the elements instead liike this - `(rotatef (nth i lst) (nth j lst))`

Comment: The error doesn't make sense for the code+input provided

Answer (score 2):

You should decide whether your `swap` will modify old list or not.

Destructive `swap` can be done with already mentioned `rotatef` or with pair of `setf`:

```
(defun swap1 (lst i j)
  (let ((temp (nth i lst)))
    (setf (nth i lst) (nth j lst))
    (setf (nth j lst) temp)
    lst))
```

Non-destructive `swap` has to work with copy of argument:

```
(defun swap2 (lst i j)
  (let* ((newlist (copy-tree lst))
         (temp (nth i newlist)))
    (setf (nth i newlist) (nth j newlist))
    (setf (nth j newlist) temp)
    newlist))
```

Comment: copy-list should be sufficient, the function only mutates the first level of depth in the list, it could be a problem if sullists in the list are deeply copied

Answer (score 2):

#### remarks

Your code looks a bit like it was inspired by Scheme: you named the variable `lst` and introduced a local variable as-if with `define` but in a way that does not work in Common Lisp, where `let` is scoped.
Moreover, you do not use the return value of [`SUBSTITUTE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_sbs_s.htm), which means that any intermediate result is discarded.
The `substitute` function is purely functional and do not change its inputs with side-effects.

```
(defun swap (lst x y)
  (let (temp (nth y lst))) ;; temp is only visible inside the let
  (substitute (nth x lst)  (nth y lst)) ;; result is discarded
  (substitute temp (nth x lst))) ;; <- the only thing actually used in swap
```

#### implementing swap

There are two possible versions for this function, one that mutates the input list, one that doesn't. You also have to decide what is or isn't a valid input and what happens when an invalid input is given.

In both cases below, I assume that `x` is strictly lower than `y`, you can make the function more robust by swapping `x` and `y` in case this is not the case, or simply returning `lst` when `x` and `y` are equal.

Note also that in case `x` and/or `y` are beyond the limit of the list, the result is going to contain `NIL` values or signal an error, you could add more checks in the below functions to avoid those problems.

#### destructive version

Here, `nswap` is the destructive version, it descends into the `list` *x* times using `nthcdr`, to the sublist that starts at position `x`.
From this sublist, it descends the remaining amount of cells to reach position *y*. The two lists `xlist` and `ylist` are lists that start at respectively position `x` and `y`.
Then, I exchange their `car` using [`ROTATEF`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_rotate.htm).

```
(defun nswap (list x y)
  (assert (< x y))
  (let* ((xlist (nthcdr x list))
         (ylist (nthcdr (- y x) xlist)))
    (prog1 list
      (rotatef (car xlist)
               (car ylist)))))
```

#### functional version

The purely functional `swap` could just call `nswap` on `(copy-list lst)`.
It is however also possible to share some cells with `lst`, since everything that follows the rest of `ylist` is left unmodified.
That's how the function works, it computes `xlist` and `ylist` as before, but uses [`LDIFF`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_ldiffc.htm) to produce fresh lists (regions of the initial list).
The different slices of the initial lists are concatenated with `nconc` (they are fresh lists, so the code has local side-effects but externally, the input list is unmodified). The `(rest ylist)` is the last argument to `nconc` and is not a copy.

```
(defun swap (list x y)
  (assert (< x y))
  (let* ((xlist (nthcdr x list))
         (ylist (nthcdr (- y x) xlist)))
    (nconc (ldiff list xlist)
           (list (first ylist))
           (ldiff (rest xlist) ylist)
           (list (first xlist))
           (rest ylist))))
```

For example, using `:circle t` for `write` let us see the shared end of list:

```
(let ((list '(a b c d e f g h i)))
  (write (list :original list
               :swapped (swap list 1 3))
         :circle t))
```

The following is printed, with `#1=` marking the tail and `#1#` showing that the identical same tail is used in the result:

```
(:ORIGINAL (A B C D . #1=(E F G H I))
 :SWAPPED (A D C B . #1#))
```